# HyperLedger Fabric 2.5 Installation

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger-fabric

I'm trying to create a sample HLF network to evaluate my thesis.
I'm using Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS and I have installed go version go1.20.3 on my ubuntu. I already done everthing in the [documentation](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html), however when I run 'make gotools' command, I get this error: make: *** No rule to make target 'gotools'.  Stop.

Can anyone help me with this?

I was doing the things on this documentation on [Setting up the development environment](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dev-setup/devenv.html)  and got the error after forking and cloning the codes on the make gotools command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The instructions for setting up a development environment (including running `make gotools`) is for setting up to develop / contribute to the Hyperledger Fabric codebase contained in the [GitHub repository](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric). If you just want to set up your own Fabric network locally, you don't need to do this. Instead, follow the *Getting Started* topics:

- [Install](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.5/getting_started.html)
- [Run Fabric](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.5/getting_started_run_fabric.html)

Another useful resource is the [Full Stack Asset Transfer Guide](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/tree/main/full-stack-asset-transfer-guide#readme) sample. This perhaps covers more areas than you need just to get started (including Kubernetes deployment), but does contain some good overview description and worked exercises for developing smart contracts and client applications that interact with those smart contracts.